# How to print array in format [1, 2, 3, 4 ,5] with string.Join in C#?

Tags: c#

I have an array in C#: `1 2 3 4 5`. I just want to print in format with [].
For example: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Comment: did you try anything yourself?

Comment: Please read tag descriptions before adding them to your question. For example console - "A mechanism for interacting with a computer operating system or software by typing commands to perform specific tasks" has nothing to do with your question. [ask]

Comment: @Sayse i can handle `console` tag but not `asp-classic`!!

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary - "console-application" I could possibly understand. The op may be working on  a legacy application that uses asp classic.. Since its highly unlikely to be working on something that uses both of these I removed all irrelevant tags. OP feel free to re-add the relevant ones

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `string.Format` and `string.Join` combined

```
var output = string.Format("[{0}]", string.Join(",", yourArray));
```

and then you just need to print `output` string anywhere you want.

`String.Format` will provide you with possibility to wrap joined string with `[` and `]` without concatenating string manually.

Comment: Thank you ! So much Hate here :D

Comment: @Nick1R1I don't think its hate. You didn't follow the guidelines for asking a question and people are just pointing that out. Think of it as constructive critisism.

Comment: @Nick1R1 and remember if you encounter any hate anytime, please report it as `rude`

Comment: @Nick1R1 did my answer helped you? If it did, please accept it as answer.

Comment: @Nick1R1 so click the tick right next to my answer :)